# How to write algorithm without numbering in latex

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am looking for the way to write a algorithm as: (without numbering). Please help me to write it in latex. Thanks in advance

```
Algorithm:
Input: A, B,C.
Initialize \alpha, \beta,u
Employ the A
While |u^(k+1)-u^k |≥ \epsilon
    Compute \alpha as \hat {\alpha} by Eq. \eqref{eq:1}.
    Compute \beta as \hat {\beta} by Eq. \eqref{eq:2}.
    Compute u as \hat u by Eq. \eqref{eq:3}.
End
Output: \alpha, \beta.
```

Comment: What do you mean *without numbering* ? Could you provide a MWE showing the problems you are facing ?

Comment: If you are using the `algorithm2e` package (which I suppose you are, given your question tags), the default option is without numbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code for your algorithm using the package `algorithm2e` as suggested by your tags:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[plainruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[ht!]
    \KwIn{%
         $A, B \text{ and } C$
         }%

         {\bf Initialization:} $\alpha, \beta \text{ and } u$ ;

    \While{$|u^{k+1}-u^k | \geq \epsilon$}{%

        compute $\alpha$ as $\hat{\alpha}$ with Eq. \eqref{eq:1};

        compute $\beta$ as $\hat{\beta}$ with Eq. \eqref{eq:2};

        compute $u$ as $\hat{u}$ with Eq. \eqref{eq:3}.
        }

     \KwOut{%
        $\alpha \text{ and } \beta$
        }%

     \caption{Some algorithm}%
     \label{algo:solution}%
     \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

And here is what the output looks like:

[image: Output from code]

There are many different options within `algorithm2e` to configure the layout of the algorithm. You can for instance replace the option `plainruled` by `plain` in order to remove the horizontal lines. More information is available in the package documentation [here](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf). See **section 7.3**.

As for the numbering of the algorithm, if you completely remove the number, you will not be able to label it and reference it in the text. Have a look at **section 9.2** and the command `\SetAlgoRefName` in order to customize the referencing.

Comment: Thank Nicolas. Is it possible to remove the vertical and horizontal dash (between while-end, and upper of input and  Algorithm1? Besides, please remove the Algorithm1 caption, just use Algorithm

Comment: I just edited the answer. Hope it helps.